# How to locate the input using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table in which I have various rows.  In the each row, the first columns contains a span that contains an input.

```
 <tr>
      <td>
           <select></select>
           <span class="comboSpan">
                <input title class="custom textbox"> 
           </span>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

[image]

How do I change the input text color using jquery?  Part of my screen is as follows:

```
 $("#tTable tbody tr").each(function () {
      var td = $(this).children('td:first');
      var span = td.children('span:first');                       
      span.children().find(':input').addClass("redColor");
 });
```

Comment: find('input') not find(':input')

Comment: most used 3 kind of selectors: select by class name is $('.myClassName'), select by id is $('#myId') and select by tag name is $('tagName')

Comment: @florin.prisecariu `:input` is fine, http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: and he wants to select all inputs, textareas, selects and buttons from that span? or just the <input> ?

Comment: just the input and the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct your script like below:

```
$("#tTable tbody tr").each(function () {
      var td = $(this).children('td:first');
      var span = td.find('span:first');// change                       
      span.find('input').addClass("redColor");// change 
 });
```

OR

you can use below code :

```
 $(function(){
      $("#tTable tbody tr td:first").find('span input').addClass('redColor');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`span.children().find(':input')` line is causing the problem. since span's direct child is the input element. And you don't need to iterate over all the tr elements.

Try,

```
$("#tTable tbody tr td:first-child span:first-of-type input").addClass("redColor");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FBw8N/)